# How create confirmation popup in kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have jquery UI code for confirm popup.

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the batchjob:' + 
 dataItem["Name"])) {
            $.get("@Url.Content("~/BatchJob/DeleteBatchJob")", { batchJobDetailId: parseInt(dataItem["BatchJobDetailId"]) }, function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    debugger
                   var batchJobValidateWnd = $("#ValidateBatchJobStatus").data("kendoWindow");
                    batchJobValidateWnd.content("BatchJob deleted successfully.");
                    batchJobValidateWnd.center().open();
                    $.post("@Url.Content("~/BatchJob/SearchBatchJobDetailByParams")", { jobName: $("#Name").val(), startDate: $("#ScheduleStartDate").val() }, function (data) {

                    });
                }
                else {
                    debugger
                    window.location = '@Url.Content("~/BatchJob/Create")/' + parseInt(dataItem["BatchJobDetailId"]);
                }
            });
        }
```

And I need Kendo Confirmation popup?How i change jquery confirm popup to kendo confirm popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Kendo Confirmation Dialog via a promise, and if confirmed execute the same way as you would with a jQuery dialog.

The dialog itself should be created using an [External Template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#render-html-encoded-values) which is rendered on `buttonDisplayDialog` `click` event which will wait for a response before continuing.

```
<script id="confirmationTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

<div class="popupMessage"></div>
  </br>
<hr/>
<div class="dialog_buttons">
    <input type="button" class="confirm_yes k-button" value="Yes" style="width: 70px" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" class="confirm_no k-button" value="No" style="width: 70px" />
  </div>

</script>
```

Based on whether the user clicks "Yes" or "No" will return `result` as a `true` or `false` value which is where you should put the remainder of your code:

```
$("#buttonDisplayDialog").kendoButton({
      click: function(e) {
        $.when(showConfirmationWindow('Are you sure you want to delete the batchjob:')).then(function(confirmed){

          if(confirmed){
            alert('This is where you will put confirmation code');
          }
          else{
            alert('User clicked no');
          }
        });
      }      
    });
  });

function showConfirmationWindow(message) {
    return showWindow('#confirmationTemplate', message)
  };

  function showWindow(template, message) {

    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    var result = false;

    $("<div id='popupWindow'></div>")
    .appendTo("body")
    .kendoWindow({
      width: "200px",
      modal: true,
      title: "",
      modal: true,
      visible: false,
      close: function (e) {
        this.destroy();
        dfd.resolve(result);
      }
    }).data('kendoWindow').content($(template).html()).center().open();

    $('.popupMessage').html(message);

    $('#popupWindow .confirm_yes').val('OK');
    $('#popupWindow .confirm_no').val('Cancel');

    $('#popupWindow .confirm_no').click(function () {
      $('#popupWindow').data('kendoWindow').close();
    });

    $('#popupWindow .confirm_yes').click(function () {
      result = true;
      $('#popupWindow').data('kendoWindow').close();
    });

    return dfd.promise();
  };
```

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/afoLIN/4) to demonstrate the above code in action.